# Tool to let make a window ignore clicks (clicks go through to the window under it)

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

Is there an app that makes a window kind of a ghost window?
I have a script running which uses mouse clicks and keyboard input and I want to be able to open a video file for example as like a ghost window which doesn't show mouse and register mouse clicks or keyboard input to it and let them go through to window to the window underneath it

Comment: Sounds useful for people who have RPA'd their job and like watching movies.